# Quill Editor and Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, quill

I'm a vue.js beginner and I've been trying to integrate the Quill editor into Vue modules. At first, I tried with the vue-quill plugin but documentation is very poor and I couldn't understand how to use it. Very frustrating.

Now I don't know if I'm better off trying to create my own plugin or if I give the existing plugin a second try and maybe try to enhance it.

What I want is someone to please provide some sample working code to get this going.

Comment: Please post something that you have tried with vue-quill. What is the error that you are getting? What is it that is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Upon inspecting the vue-quill *package.json* file I noticed it depended on an old version of quill :

```
"dependencies": {
   "quill": "^0.20.1",
   ...
}
```

Since I was getting fragment errors from that build I decided to take the original code to suit my needs. At this point, you can [copy this modified component](https://gist.github.com/PZ01/f317d92d039313cc4b986112ee8b69ba) and use something like [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) to use it.

I can't give you precise steps on vue-cli because my project is based on Laravel, but the idea of storing different .vue files into a components folder should be similar.

Finally, I simply use the component in one of my views :

```
<quill :content.sync="content"></quill>
```

Note : I am still fiddling around the component that I uploaded on gist, so take it as a starting point. The code is fairly simple.